# Switching out 8 ohm speakers for original 4 ohm speakers

Tags: speakers

I've been given an inexpensive "all-in-one" stereo receiver/cd player/turntable that outputs to two tiny built-in 4 ohm speakers.  Can I cut out the 4 ohm speakers and route the output to an inexpensive set of external 8 ohm two-way speakers?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. 8 Ω > 4 Ω so they will draw less current from the amplifiers so there is no risk of damage. You may notice a reduction in maximum volume but, if the new speakers are more efficient, you may not!

Comment: Thanks.  The unit's in a very old basement (circa 1908) where I'm doing some on-going work and the 4 ohm speakers just don't have enough "push" to carry over an 85 foot run.

Comment: This is true for 99.99 % of audio amplifiers. Once in my life I have experienced an amplifier which would self-oscillate in the MHz range and heating up until unplugged at 8 ohm but stable at 4 ohm. Such designs should be left oscillating until destruction so they won’t hurt anyone more.

Comment: speaker impedance is somewhat complicated because it changes with frequency so we just use 3db reduction as a rule of thumb, in other words the reduction won't be huge.